# Cannot stringify a function when using axios get within nuxtServerInit

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, nuxt.js

i am trying Udemy Nuxt.js course connect my app to the backend,
when trying the following code i got GET http://localhost:3000/ 500 (Internal Server Error) on the client side,

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios';
const createStore = () => {
    return new Vuex.Store({
        state: {
            loadedPosts: [],
        },
        mutations: {
            setPosts(state, posts) {
                state.loadedPosts = posts;
            },
        },
        actions: {
          nuxtServerInit(vuexContext, context) {
               return axios
                .get('https://nuxt-blog-7a712.firebaseio.com/posts.json')
                .then((res) => {
                    const postArray = [];
                    for (const key in res.data) {
                        postArray.push({ ...res.data[key], id: key });
                    }
                    vuexContext.commit('setPost', postArray);
                })
                .catch((e) => context.error(e));
        },
```

> WARN  Cannot stringify a function transformRequest
>
> WARN  Cannot stringify a function transformResponse
>
> WARN  Cannot stringify a function httpAdapter
>
> WARN  Cannot stringify a function validateStatus
>
> WARN  Cannot stringify arbitrary non-POJOs Writable
>
> WARN  Cannot stringify a function

i have google it to find some answers but couldn't find a fix, some posts talked about devalue package but do not know about this package usage

Answer (score 3):

maybe late, but I had trouble with this as well. The warnings are not what are breaking your code, they are [just warnings](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/4026).

What is breaking your code has to be something else, but looking at your code I can't find it..

try changing

```
.catch((e) => context.error(e));
```

to

```
.catch((e) => console.log(e); context.error(e));
```

to get a better idea of what is going wrong!